# How can I exclude multiple files from splitchunk webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-splitchunks

**Question**

I need to exclude multiple files from webpack optimization from splitchunk plugin.

**What I've tried**

```
const excludedFiles = ['file 1', 'file 2'];

module.exports = {
  //...
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks (chunk) {
        // exclude `my-excluded-chunk`
        return !excludedFiles.includes(chunk.name);
      }
    }
  }
};
```

**Result**

It seems the files are not excluded.

How can achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. Note that chunk is not equal to a file. Modules (1 module ~ 1 file) are combined into chunks, chunks into chunk groups and groups into chunk graph. So, a filename doesn't mean it is chunk.

The options `chunks` in `optimization.splitChunks` means that which chuck to exclude or include during the optimization process. So, it means you can exclude a chunk but not individual file.

If you want to do what you are trying to achieve then, using [`externals`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) is a way to go. It is not exactly same but almost equivalent to your needs.